# Django + React App: Getting 404 Errors for Static Files

Tags: reactjs, django

I am currently working on a Django + React web application and I've encountered an issue with serving static files. The Django development server is returning 404 errors for several static files and images, like images "K5.png," "earth.png," and "manifest.json."

Yes, the website loads, except for the images.

This is how I refer to my images (example):

```
<img src="/earth.png" alt="" className="earth w-fit mx-auto"/>
```

I've configured my settings as follows:

```py
STATIC_URL = 'static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR_FRONTEND, 'frontend/build/'),
]
```

```
import os
from pathlib import Path

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR_BACKEND = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
BASE_DIR_FRONTEND = os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR_BACKEND)

# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []

CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    # Installed Application
    'api',
    'rest_framework',
    'djongo',
    'pymongo',
    "corsheaders",
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    "corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware",
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

CORS_ALLOW_METHODS = (
    "GET",
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'project_k5.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR_BACKEND, '../frontend/build')]
        ,
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'project_k5.wsgi.application'


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = 'static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR_FRONTEND, 'frontend/build/'),
]

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
```

Here's what my console output looks like:

```
[19/Oct/2023 09:38:38] "GET /K5.png HTTP/1.1" 404 2317
[19/Oct/2023 09:38:38] "GET /earth.png HTTP/1.1" 404 2326
[19/Oct/2023 09:38:38] "GET /manifest.json HTTP/1.1" 404 2338
```

Here's my project structure after running pnpm run build:

```
PROJECT KS
├── .github
├── idea
│   └── Build
│       └── static
│          ├── asset-manifest.json
│          ├── earth.png
│          ├── favicon.ico
│          ├── index.html
│          ├── K5.png
│          ├── logo192.png
│          ├── logo512.png
│          ├── manifest.json
│          └── robots.ext
├── backend
└── frontend
    └── node_modules
    └── public
        ├── earth.png
        ├── favicon.ico
        ├── index.html
        ├── K5.png
        ├── logo192.png
        ├── logo512.png
        ├── manifest.json
        └── robots.txt
```

I have already verified that these static files exist in the specified directory, and the paths in my templates are correctly set to access these files. However, I'm still getting these 404 errors.

Can anyone help me diagnose the issue and suggest a solution? I would appreciate any guidance to resolve this problem and make my static files load as expected.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: #1 Be careful with the mongo credentials #2 How are  you running the app?

Comment: @JRichardsz Hi! Thank you for that caution. I am running the app through python manage.py runserver

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Django's method of grabbing static files. instead of using `src="/earth.png`

```html
<img src="{% static 'earth.png' %}" alt="" className="earth w-fit mx-auto"/>
```

Comment: Hi! I did try that. However, it doesn't work either:

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
Django version 4.1.11, using settings 'project_k5.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
[19/Oct/2023 13:01:56] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 644
Not Found: /{%static 'earth.png'%}
Not Found: /K5.png
[19/Oct/2023 13:01:56] "GET /%7B%static%20'earth.png'%%7D HTTP/1.1" 404 2405
[19/Oct/2023 13:01:56] "GET /K5.png HTTP/1.1" 404 2317
Not Found: /manifest.json
[19/Oct/2023 13:01:56] "GET /manifest.json HTTP/1.1" 404 2338